# Google cloud engine external access issue

Tags: node.js, networking, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Google cloud platform and I didn't understand why I cannot reach a node.js instance running on a new VM.

Node is running on port 8084 through `app.listen('8084', "0.0.0.0")`

Firewall rules are the following:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME                    NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY  DISABLED
default-allow-http      default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80                              False
default-allow-https     default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443                             False
default-allow-icmp      default  INGRESS    65534     icmp                                False
default-allow-internal  default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp        False
default-allow-rdp       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389                            False
default-allow-ssh       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22                              False
node-8084               default  INGRESS    999       tcp:8084                            False
```

netstat:

```
netstat -na | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8084            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34339         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8998          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:65001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::970                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::980                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::922                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

I can reach the VM via SSH (port 22) but not through `http://35.206.91.238:8084/medical` on Chrome. 35.206.91.238 is the external IP showed by google cloud console.

Node.js presents no errors (and no requests).
main code is

```
var app = express();

app.get('/medical', function(request, response){
  if( request.query.q ) 
    run(request.query.q, function(results, queries) { parseResult(q, results, queries, response) } );
}) 
app.listen('8084', '0.0.0.0')
console.log('Server started on port 8084');  
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Wireshark traffic is only [image]
Only SYN is passing, chrome says "35.206.91.238 refused to connect."
Node is executed manually from shell and doesn't report any error after "Server started on port 8084".

Any idea

Comment: 1) The rule node-8084 allows port 8084 - good. 2) You have a process listening on port 8084 for the public interface - good. 3) There must be a problem with your node.js code. Show the code in your question. 4) Look at your log files for errors reported by your node.js code. 4) What client software are you using to connect to port 8084. Show the method and exact error messages.

Comment: thanks for analysis. I've edited to add information. (node application works fine locally on my Mac)

Comment: The code you posted listens on localhost only. This does not match your question or the results of netstat. What do the log files show? How are you testing this? Please provide accurate information for everything.

Comment: I've reported code executed locally on my Mac, while in server I use "app.listen('8084', '0.0.0.0')" for binding. Sorry for mistake. I added some other information with Wireshark sniffing

Comment: The Wireshark trace shows the connection is being closed (RST, ACK) as nobody is listening on the port. You do not have a server (your software) correctly functioning on port 8084.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment. Firewalls (good ones) do not ACK or RST SYN. They should drop the connection (no response) to stay stealthy. The ACK part of RST, ACK is to acknowledge the previous SYN. The RST means that the connection is being closed. The IP stack is combining two messages into one packet.This usually means there is no process listening on the port to forward the connection to. The software that you are running is opening two connections to your instance (from port 52086 and port 52087). Both connection attempts are failing.

Comment: thanks for clarifications. It's not clear to me how is possible with netstat saying "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8084            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN"

Comment: Well, you have the Wireshark details. The mystery is why your software is not working correctly. Do you have a software firewall running on this instance that is getting in the way? Try changing your software to use port 80 and retest.

Comment: Does your app respond locally when you enter `curl localhost:8084` on the server console? What are allowed targets for the firewall rule `node-8084`: "All instances in the network" or "Specified target tags"? In the latter case: is a correct network tag is set for the VM instance?

Comment: yes it works locally with curl request. The target is "All instances in the network"